# sql filter rows based on condition parent to child hierarchy

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Erwin, My bad with the correct example and data. Please find below the updated query with all data as required. 
  We have master table with all the relationships between the asset IDs as shown below. The asset hierarchy is S1 which has F11, F12, F13, and inturn F11 has D111, D112,D113, similarly F12 has D121,D122,D123 and so on .

MASTER TABLE AND INSERT SCRIPTS

Please refer to the link [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9dd12)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl2 (c_id text ,d_id text, f_id text, s_id text);
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019403','D111','F11','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019404','D112','F11','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019405','D113','F11','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019406','D111','F11','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019407','D112','F11','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019408','D121','F12','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019409','D122','F12','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019410','D123','F12','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019411','D123','F12','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019412','D141','F14','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019413','D131','F13','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019414','D142','F14','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019415','D132','F13','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019416','D143','F14','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019417','D133','F13','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019418','D144','F14','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019419','D211','F21','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019420','D212','F21','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019421','D213','F21','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019422','D211','F21','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019423','D212','F21','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019424','D221','F22','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019425','D222','F22','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019426','D223','F22','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019427','D223','F22','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019428','D241','F24','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019429','D231','F23','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019430','D242','F24','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019431','D232','F23','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019432','D243','F24','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019433','D233','F23','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019434','D244','F24','S2');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019435','D311','F31','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019436','D312','F31','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019437','D313','F31','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019438','D311','F31','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019439','D312','F31','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019440','D321','F32','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019441','D322','F32','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019442','D323','F32','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019443','D323','F32','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019444','D341','F34','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019445','D331','F33','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019446','D342','F34','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019447','D332','F33','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019448','D343','F34','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019449','D333','F33','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019450','D344','F34','S3');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019451','D111','F11','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019452','D112','F11','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019453','D113','F11','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019454','D111','F11','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019455','D112','F11','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019456','D121','F12','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019457','D122','F12','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019458','D123','F12','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019459','D123','F12','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019460','D141','F14','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019461','D131','F13','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019462','D142','F14','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019463','D132','F13','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019464','D143','F14','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019465','D133','F13','S1');
INSERT INTO tbl2 values('100000019466','D144','F14','S1');
```

We have the transaction table with the asset ID, which gives information about failed asset only. Suppose if the asset ID which is at a higher level has failed, the data for the child is also populated but while fetching the records we need to ignore the child ones and get only the highest level.

Transaction Data is available for 3 days which discusses three different scenarios.
 Scenario 1 for 2013-10-10 which talks about S1 asset has failed which also gives child records which needs to be ignored.

Scenario 2 for 2013-10-11 which talks about F21, F22, F23 failures along with its child records. We need to ignore the children. Observe that the asset ID S1 has not failed and hence will not be present in the transaction table for scenario 2

Scenario 3 for 2013-10-12 which talks about F33 failure along with its children D331, D332, D333. We need to consider only F33 and ignore children. Consider the D311, D312, D313, D321, D322 and D323.

We always need to group by startdatetime field since parent and child records will always have this column value same for a given entry.

Refer to the above link which also has the transactional table and data

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (startdatetime text, enddatetime text, assetid text);

INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-10 22:10:11', '2013-10-10 22:10:11', 'S1');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-10 22:10:11', '2013-10-10 22:10:11', 'F11');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-10 22:10:11', '2013-10-10 22:10:11', 'F12');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-10 22:10:11', '2013-10-10 22:10:11', 'F13');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-10 22:10:11', '2013-10-10 22:10:11', 'D111');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-10 22:10:11', '2013-10-10 22:10:11', 'D112');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-10 22:10:11', '2013-10-10 22:10:11', 'D113');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-10 22:10:11', '2013-10-10 22:10:11', 'D121');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-10 22:10:11', '2013-10-10 22:10:11', 'D122');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-10 22:10:11', '2013-10-10 22:10:11', 'D123');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-10 22:10:11', '2013-10-10 22:10:11', 'D131');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-10 22:10:11', '2013-10-10 22:10:11', 'D132');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-10 22:10:11', '2013-10-10 22:10:11', 'D133');

 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-11 22:10:11', '2013-10-11 22:12:11', 'F21');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-11 22:10:11', '2013-10-11 22:12:11', 'F22');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-11 22:10:11', '2013-10-11 22:12:11', 'F23');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-11 22:10:11', '2013-10-11 22:12:11', 'D211');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-11 22:10:11', '2013-10-11 22:12:11', 'D212');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-11 22:10:11', '2013-10-11 22:12:11', 'D213');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-11 22:10:11', '2013-10-11 22:12:11', 'D221');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-11 22:10:11', '2013-10-11 22:12:11', 'D222');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-11 22:10:11', '2013-10-11 22:12:11', 'D223');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-11 22:10:11', '2013-10-11 22:12:11', 'D231');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-11 22:10:11', '2013-10-11 22:12:11', 'D232');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-11 22:10:11', '2013-10-11 22:12:11', 'D233');

 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-12 22:10:11', '2013-10-12 22:16:11', 'F33');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-12 22:10:11', '2013-10-12 22:16:11', 'D311');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-12 22:10:11', '2013-10-12 22:16:11', 'D312');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-12 22:10:11', '2013-10-12 22:16:11', 'D313');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-12 22:10:11', '2013-10-12 22:16:11', 'D321');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-12 22:10:11', '2013-10-12 22:16:11', 'D322');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-12 22:10:11', '2013-10-12 22:16:11', 'D323');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-12 22:10:11', '2013-10-12 22:16:11', 'D331');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-12 22:10:11', '2013-10-12 22:16:11', 'D332');
 INSERT INTO tbl1  values('2013-10-12 22:10:11', '2013-10-12 22:16:11', 'D333');
```

Expected Ouput:

Count of the consumers which have been affected based on the transaction data table.

Please help me with the c_id record details for above scenario and I will get the count.

Comment: Still show your query, please, even if it's not working at all. It often clarifies what you are after. It's unclear so far, which columns should be in the result or how the rows should be ordered.

Comment: Also, the hierarchy seems completely irrelevant. Associated IDs are always ignored in your examples, regardless of hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **case1** : s_id is present then neglect the child(f_id) and subchild(d_id) rows

Using [**CTEs**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html), a solution can look like this:

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT d_id, f_id
   FROM   tbl2 t2
   JOIN   tbl1 t1 ON t1.assetid = t2.s_id
   )
SELECT t.*
FROM   tbl1 t
LEFT   JOIN d ON d.d_id = t.assetid
LEFT   JOIN f ON f.f_id = t.assetid
WHERE  d.d_id IS NULL
AND    f.f_id IS NULL
```

#### Explain

- CTE `x` identifies `d_id` and  `f_id` that shall be ignored.
- The main SELECT left joins to this exclude table x twice, to eliminate rows matching on `d_id` or `f_id`.

> **case2** : f_id is present then neglect the parent(s_id) and lower(d_id)

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT d_id, s_id
   FROM   tbl2 f
   JOIN   tbl1 t ON t.assetid = f.f_id
   )
SELECT t.*
FROM   tbl1 t
LEFT   JOIN x d ON d.d_id = t.assetid
LEFT   JOIN x s ON s.s_id = t.assetid
WHERE  d.d_id IS NULL
AND    s.s_id IS NULL;
```

[**-> SQLfiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/da683/2)

> **case3** : d_id is present then neglect the parent s_id,f_id

You got it, don't you?

Comment: @sandy067: I think you are mistaken. The query should work as is. `d_id` and `f_id` where switched in your fiddle. Consider / compare [this fixed fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8c443/8).

Comment: Thanks Erwin This was what exactly i was looking for although here is the link for the expected output [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/60856/5).

One single query returns me all the results I was expecting.

Sorry there is a possibility that I might have different time records for a given asset ID which I need to capture and which is present in the latest fiddle provided above.

Thanks a ton for you help !!!